# text-overflow: ellipsis; не до конца обрезает текст

Tags: html, css

нужно реализовать ломания текста, чтобы при уменьшении экрана, те буквы, что в конце текста делались точечками ' ... '. Я добавил все свойства что нужно, и оно вроди как работает, но там буквально пару букв становиться точками, а дальше оно уже не хочет ломаться, и просто уходит за экран.

Блок називаеться mail__column-text

[ссылка на codepan](https://codepen.io/NikitaPetrov123/pen/abpgzRG)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: "";
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
    font-size: 66px;
    line-height: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.section {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.button {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffd237 0%, #b4962f 100%);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.button:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.button:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.button a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-0.07deg);
    transform: rotate(-0.07deg);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #000;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.paragraph {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #9c9c9c;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.input:focus, .input:active {
    outline: none;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.header {
    padding: 30px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}

.header__row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__logo {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.header__logo img {
    max-width: 50px;
}

.header__account {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.header__account span {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header__account img {
    max-width: 50px;
}

.mail__row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
}

.mail__nav ul li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.mail__nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #f4e4e4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mail__nav ul li a {
    color: #000;
}

.mail__nav-item--active {
    background-color: #f4e4e4;
}

.mail__column-message {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.mail__column-name {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

.mail__column-name img {
    max-width: 20px;
}

.mail__column-describe {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mail__column-describe h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mail__column-text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mail__column-date {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
    column-gap: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.mail__column-date img {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 20px;
    flex: 0 0 20px;
}

.mail__column-date span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <section class="mail">
            <div class="mail__row">
               <div class="mail__column">
                  <nav class="mail__nav">
                     <ul>
                        <li class="mail__nav-item mail__nav-item--active"> <img src="./assets/images/incom.png"
                              alt="incom">
                           <a href="#">Incoming</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mail__nav-item "> <img src="./assets/images/outcom.png" alt="outcom"> <a
                              href="#">Outgoing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mail__nav-item "> <img src="./assets/images/draft.png" alt="draft"> <a
                              href="#">Drafts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mail__nav-item "> <img src="./assets/images/spam.png" alt="spam"> <a
                              href="#">Spam</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="mail__column">
                  <div class="mail__column-message">
                     <div class="mail__column-name">
                        <img src="./assets/images/star1.svg" alt="star">
                        <span>Me, Alex</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="mail__column-describe">
                        <h2>Trip to qwqSouth America</h2>
                        <div class="mail__column-text"> -
                           qqwwqqq Susut d otwqeq
                        </div>
                        <div class="mail__column-date">
                           <img src="./assets/images/attach_26.png" alt="attach">
                           <span>12 apr.</span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mail__column-message">
                     <div class="mail__column-name">
                        <img src="./assets/images/star1.svg" alt="star">
                        <span>Me, Alex</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="mail__column-describe">
                        <h2>Trip to South America</h2>
                        <div class="mail__column-text">
                           - qqqSuspendisse ut dot
                        </div>
                        <div class="mail__column-date">
                           <img src="./assets/images/attach_26.png" alt="attach">
                           <span>12 apr.</span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> но там буквально пару букв становиться точками, а дальше оно уже не
> хочет ломаться, и просто уходит за экран.

Как понять "дальше не хочет ломаться"? Вы понимаете что вообще делает css-свойство *text-overflow: ellipsis*?
Если текст не помещается в заданную область, то он обрезается и к концу видимой строки добавляется многоточие.
Если я правильно понимаю, то вы хотите контролировать видимую длину текста, но вы не сможете это сделать стандартными средствами html. Для этого вам надо либо js, либо php использовать.